# usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to upload my peer project details to shinyio and its breaking with the subject message.

RStudio is showing that the publish is successful. However shiny is throwing the error message in subject. When looked into the log I found the message

> lib = “/usr/local/lib/R/site-library”’ is not writable

I don't find such directory in my system. So where ever R is installed, I gave full permission to it and its subfolders.

Also, in the shiny dashboard, I found the below message, however I used only 2 hrs till now and the free offer is valid till mid Jan 2018.

> Account is suspended until {{ suspended_until | date:'medium' }} due to "{{ currentAccount['suspended_reason'] | lowercase }}".
>   All of your applications will be unavailable until then, or you can upgrade your account.

I tried all the possible recommendations that are available in internet but could not succeed.

I'm using Win7/10

Comment: Please provide some more details around what this is about. What "shiny" are you talking about? Have you checked all resources available to you, like help and support of the "shiny"?

Comment: Do you have any `install.packages()` calls in your app? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shinyapps-users/uX22Tu_veOM

Answer (score -1):

I think I exhausted all the available resources as I'm doing this for the past 2 days.

Here's what I'm doing.

As part of the "Developing data products" course, I created a shiny application that I'm expected to upload to shiny server. When uploaded to the shiny server is were the errors that I mentioned are coming up

```
2017-12-11T08:32:33.609020+00:00 shinyapps[246840]: Stack trace (innermost first):
2017-12-11T08:32:33.609023+00:00 shinyapps[246840]:     12: fn
2017-12-11T08:32:33.609023+00:00 shinyapps[246840]:     11: doTryCatch
2017-12-11T08:32:33.609024+00:00 shinyapps[246840]:     10: tryCatchOne
2017-12-11T08:32:33.609024+00:00 shinyapps[246840]:      9: tryCatchList
2017-12-11T08:32:33.609025+00:00 shinyapps[246840]:      8: tryCatch
2017-12-11T08:32:33.609025+00:00 shinyapps[246840]:      7: connect$retry
2017-12-11T08:32:33.609026+00:00 shinyapps[246840]:      6: eval
2017-12-11T08:32:33.609026+00:00 shinyapps[246840]:      5: eval
2017-12-11T08:32:33.609027+00:00 shinyapps[246840]:      4: eval
2017-12-11T08:32:33.609027+00:00 shinyapps[246840]:      3: eval
2017-12-11T08:32:33.609028+00:00 shinyapps[246840]:      2: eval.parent
2017-12-11T08:32:33.609028+00:00 shinyapps[246840]:      1: local
2017-12-11T08:32:33.609335+00:00 shinyapps[246840]: Error : An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.
2017-12-11T08:32:33.604126+00:00 shinyapps[246840]: **Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’**
2017-12-11T08:32:33.609021+00:00 shinyapps[246840]:     53: install.packages
```